# How do I use the variable of the selected folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

When i select a folder manually, through FolderBrowserDialog, my need to substitute the path to the code below.

Where "%ProgramFiles (x86)%\MyApp" must be replaced with the variable of the selected folder + file name.

As a result, when selecting a folder, the file size "testFile.txt" in "label1" should be displayed (there will be two or more such files).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = folderBrowser.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Determine the size of the file in KB (dividing the number of bytes by 1024)
            FileInfo fs1 = new FileInfo(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp\\testFile.txt"));
            long FileSize1 = fs1.Length / 1024;
            label1.Text = "testFile.txt (" + Convert.ToString(FileSize1) + " KB)";
            if (FileSize1 > 180 & FileSize1 < 186) // If the file is larger and smaller than the specified sizes
            {
                label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Decision, edit:

```
            FileInfo fs1 = new FileInfo(folderBrowser.SelectedPath + "\\testFile.txt");
```

or

```
            FileInfo fs1 = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(folderBrowser.SelectedPath, "testFile.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation has an item dedicated specifically to this: [How to: Choose Folders with the Windows Forms FolderBrowserDialog Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-choose-folders-with-the-windows-forms-folderbrowserdialog-component)

> To choose folders with the FolderBrowserDialog component
>
> 1. In a procedure, check the FolderBrowserDialog component's DialogResult property to see how the dialog box was closed and get the
>      value of the FolderBrowserDialog component's SelectedPath property.
> 2. If you need to set the top-most folder that will appear within the tree view of the dialog box, set the RootFolder property, which takes
>      a member of the Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration.
> 3. Additionally, you can set the Description property, which specifies the text string that appears at the top of the
>      folder-browser tree view.
>
> In the example below, the FolderBrowserDialog component is used to
>   select a folder, similar to when you create a project in Visual Studio
>   and are prompted to select a folder to save it in. In this example,
>   the folder name is then displayed in a TextBox control on the form. It
>   is a good idea to place the location in an editable area, such as a
>   TextBox control, so that users may edit their selection in case of
>   error or other issues. This example assumes a form with a
>   FolderBrowserDialog component and a TextBox control.
>
> ```
> public void ChooseFolder()
> {
>     if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
>     {
>         textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
>     }
> }
> ```

According to that example, you can get a string to the chosen folder using `folderBrowser.SelectedPath`.

Comment: @Vitokhv What do you mean?

Comment: Under your reference I understand nothing, the example uses code for the TextBox

Comment: @Vitokhv No, it uses `FolderBrowserDialog`, just like you. Please read the example's explanatory text, not just the code. I'll add it to the answer just for future reference.

Comment: I need to set a variable to a string `FileInfo fs1 = new FileInfo(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\MyApp\\testFile.txt"));` to get something like this `FileInfo fs1 = new FileInfo(result + "testFile.txt"));`

Comment: So... Did you copy-paste that `new FileInfo(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFil‌​es(x86)%\\MyApp\\tes‌​tFile.txt"));` code from somewhere without understanding it? Or do you not understand *variable assignment expressions*? (of all things) 

Comment: I do not understand how to implement the variable of the selected folder instead of the static path...

Comment: I know what you don't understand. I'm asking you ***why***, out of two plausible reasons, you don't understand it...  I will only give you the solution after that.

Comment: Because the example shows a TextBox I need to use a variable, not a TextBox.

Comment: @Vitokhv That's not what I asked you. Did you **A)** Copy-paste code that you don't understand. or **B)** Do you not understand simple assignment expressions? --- Which one of these two?

Comment: B) and I communicate with you through google translate

Comment: @Vitokhv Ok. Here goes the explanation: `FileInfo fs1` declares a variable named `fs1` with the type of `FileInfo`. That alone only reserves space in memory, but doesn't anything in it. You have to **assign** (`=`) something to the variable, otherwise it will be `null`. To do that, you have to **create** the something to be assigned. That's the `new FileInfo( /*parameters*/ );` part. The **parameters** you pass during creation are what the path is going to be. So just change that to the selected value as shown in the example: `FileInfo fs1 = new FileInfo(folderBrowser.SelectedPath);`

Comment: Thank you! happened!
 `FileInfo fs1 = new FileInfo(folderBrowser.SelectedPath + "\\testFile.txt");`

Comment: @Vitokhv No problem. Glad to help.  --- But seriously: If you don't understand how assignments or method parameters work yet, you should work on learning that first, before trying more advanced stuff... "Learn to crawl before you try to walk, and learn to walk before you try to run", as the saying goes. 